# setting up subdomain on ubuntu server

Tags: server, apache2, websites

I have a server at mysite.no-ip.org. Everything is working fine and I have a blog and owncloud that I access writing mysite.no-ip.org/blog and mysite.no-ip.org/owncloud.
Now, I want to create subdomains so that I can write blog.mysite.no-ip.org and owncloud.mysite.no-ip.org.

I have looked a lot into it and the simplest tutorial was this one which I followed. 
http://www.bcat.eu/blog/local-subdomains-under-ubuntu-linux-and-apache-2-4-tutorial/
Except that I am not on my server but ssh into it remotely so if I use localhost I cannot see if this works I believe. This is my first obstacle, can I follow this tutorial without being present next to the server?

I also just discovered CNAME records which (I am not completely sure) seem necessary to what I want to do. I use no-ip.org and I have tried to follow something like this but this is not really clear either https://support.uberflip.com/entries/235780-4-4-5-how-to-setup-a-cname-redirect#noip

Does anyone have any pointers? This is quite shady to me and I have no idea if I am far from the solution or really close (at least if I could try localhost that would be a first step in order to check my Apache conf but I can't even do it since I ssh).

Anyways, thanks for your help in advance. Any help, link is welcomed.

Comment: You can find the solution at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43470374/set-ssl-for-my-virtual-host/77502430#77502430

Answer (score 74, accepted):

This is actually really easy.

First make sure your DNS is working. You can use a `A`, `AAAA` or `CNAME` record as long as it points to your IP address.

**Please check if it's working before you continue!** This will save you much trouble. You can check using `ping subdomain.mydomain.com` or `nslookup subdomain.mydomain.com`. If it's pointing to your IP address you're good.

Note that DNS changes may take up to 24 hours. If you want to continue now, you can edit your hosts file to manually add the sub domain. Note that this will only work for your current PC so you should check your DNS again 24 hours later to make sure it's working elsewhere as well (don't forget to revert your changes to your hosts file before you check).

To do this:

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

add line like (replacing the IP and hostname of course):

```
34.54.235.64 subdomain.mydomain.com
```

and save the file.

Now update your Apache2 configuration.

Just adding this VirtualHost will do:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName subdomain.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/subdomain.mydomain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Now create `/var/www/subdomain.mydomain.com` and restart Apache2:

```
mkdir -p /var/www/subdomain.mydomain.com
sudo service apache2 restart
```

enable the site:

```
sudo a2ensite subdomain.mydomain.com
```

Repeat this for every sub domain you want to add.

Comment: Great this works! Thank you very much. Last point, but it might be because of no-ip, I managed to make it work but using the address blog-mysite.no-ip.org when I registered the subdomain. I couldnt write blog.mysite.no-ip.org (message:invalid hostname)...now, is this because no-ip wants me to pay or did I do something wrong?

Comment: I don't know if no-ip allows you to create sub domains. If they do, it may take 24 hours before it's working as I said in my answer. Try to reach it again tomorrow. Also, I see you're using `blog-mysite` first and then `blog.mysite`. This is not the same, so if you chose the first you'll have to use that one. Don't forget to update your Apache2 config in that case.

Comment: Hey, yes sorry that is what I meant. No-ip would only let me create a subdomain with a dash and not a period. Is this no-ip restricting my free account with them? There shouldnt be reason you couldnt otherwise, should it?

Comment: I think so. I don't use no-ip. If you really want to know you should contact their support. You could also buy your own domain (like mydomain.com). This way you'll have full control of your DNS and you can add as many subdomains you want. It's not so expensive, just make sure you don't order hosting with it (this makes it expensive). Prices are usually per year and I think you can get a domain for around 10$/year.

Comment: I rolled back the last edit, as changing ownership to the apache user on the document root directory is not needed, and can even be a security risk. It is enough to give read access to the directory.

Comment: @user1983400 consider service slike heroku or appengine as an alternative to no-ip

Comment: Thank you for the ping tip, that made it clear that the sub1.mysite.com was not even resolved to my server's IP

Answer (score 0):

In my case, all I was missing was to add A record in my Godaddy domain DNS settings.

Remember I had to also add the VirtualHost and a2ensite as well.

---

```
cp /etc/apache2/site-available/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/site-avaiable/subdomain.mydomain.com 

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName subdomain.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/subdomain.mydomain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

a2ensite

```
sudo a2ensite subdomain.mydomain.com
```

restart apache
sudo systremctl reload apache2

Answer (score 0):

In my case, all I was missing was to add A record in my Godaddy domain DNS settings.

[insert A record for subdomain](https://youtu.be/mn65ZOsxG8M?si=iVi6e3F0fWG-MmN0)

Remember I had to also add the VirtualHost and a2ensite as well.

---

```
   /etc/apache2/sites-available
cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/subdomain.mydomain.com 

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName subdomain.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/subdomain.mydomain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

a2ensite

```
sudo a2ensite subdomain.mydomain.com
```

restart apache
sudo systremctl reload apache2