# Associate part of VPS server to an external subdomain

Tags: server, apache2

I have a VPS accessible on Internet (Ubuntu distro). I also have a domain name and a subdomain name coming from another host (let's say *mydomain.com* and *sub.mydomain.com*).

In the meantime I have installed Django for development on my VPS and I want to put it in production.

That configuration being specific, what could I do to associate my Django application installed on the VPS to the subdomain *sub.mydomain.com*?

And generally speaking, what are the steps to associate a part of a VPS (e.g a folder located in /www) to an external subdomain?
I must say I'm a little bit stuck despite of many resources on the web. The fact is I'm a little bit lost between subdomains, virtual hosts and all that stuff.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setting up subdomain on ubuntu server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/463618/setting-up-subdomain-on-ubuntu-server)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a domain to ip address?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/900523/how-to-set-a-domain-to-ip-address)